# Sudoku solver with Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on its Iterator

Tags: java, hashset, concurrentmodification

I'm getting the following errors:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:810)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:845)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:143)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:168)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:153)
        at sudoku.Main.main(Main.java:284)
```

I don't understand the `java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next` and `java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry` error messages, as I'm not able to get the keySet for a `HashSet` explicitly I assumed the Iterator was going through the keySet by default.

I'm not using threads, just recursive calls.
What's going on here?

```
 static void solve2(int row, int col, int [][]grid,  ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> availableNumsInRows,
          ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> availableNumsInColumns){

     if (row>=grid.length){

           System.out.println("solution found");
            printSolvedGrid(grid);

            System.out.println("move count for this sudoku is " + moveCounter);
            moveCounter=0; //reset counter
           return;


       }

       if( grid[row][col] != 0 ){
            next2( row, col, grid, availableNumsInRows, availableNumsInColumns ) ;
       }

       else {
         // Find a valid number for the empty cell

         Iterator <Integer> iterator = availableNumsInRows.get(row).iterator();


         for( int num = iterator.next() ; iterator.hasNext(); num = iterator.next())
         {
            if( checkRow(row,num,grid) && checkCol(col,num,grid) && checkBox(row,col,num,grid) )
            {
               grid[row][col] = num ;
               availableNumsInRows.get(row).remove(new Integer(num));
               availableNumsInColumns.get(col).remove(new Integer(num));
               moveCounter++;

               //printSolvedGrid(grid);
               next2( row, col, grid, availableNumsInRows, availableNumsInColumns );

            }
         }

         grid[row][col] = 0 ;
       }

  }

  //helper function for the first solution approach
  public static void next2( int row, int col, int [][] grid ,  ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> availableNumsInRows,
          ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> availableNumsInColumns )
   {
      if( col < 8 ) //pass to next col
         solve2( row, col + 1, grid, availableNumsInRows, availableNumsInColumns) ;
      else //pass to next row
         solve2( row + 1, 0, grid, availableNumsInRows, availableNumsInColumns) ;
   }
```

Edit:

I changed the code to:

```
   while (iterator.hasNext())
             {

                num=iterator.next();

                if( checkRow(row,num,grid) && checkCol(col,num,grid) && checkBox(row,col,num,grid) )
                {
                   grid[row][col] = num ;

                   iterator.remove();

                   moveCounter++;


                   next2( row, col, grid, availableNumsInRows, availableNumsInColumns );

                }

             }
```

and I'm still getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`, why is this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:810)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:845)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:148)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:175)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:137)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:175)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:159)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:175)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:137)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:175)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:159)
        at sudoku.Main.next2(Main.java:175)
        at sudoku.Main.solve2(Main.java:159)
        at sudoku.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: I'm suspicious that your code has changed a bit, but the line numbers in the stack trace have not (810, 845). Are you sure you are executing the new code?

Comment: Yes, also the line numbers (and number of error marks) in the stack trace do change after the first three messages :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the hash map but also modifying it in the same loop. That will cause exactly this exception.

You can avoid this *within one call* by calling `iterator.remove()` instead of `availableNumsInRows.get(row).remove(new Integer(num));`

However, you're recursing, creating a new iterator each time. If you remove something via one of the iterators in the *nested* call, then when you come to iterate in the *outer* call, you'll have the same problem.

One option would be to simplify the code to avoid recursing in this way; another would be to use a single iterator and pass that around.

Comment: I tried this mod but I'm still getting ConcurrentModificationException, please read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the Map while iterating over it.

Instead of this

```
availableNumsInRows.get(row).remove(new Integer(num));
```

Try this

```
iterator.remove();
```

It might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify collection via calls to it's iterator while you iterating through it, otherwise `ConcurrentModificationException` will occur:

```
...
availableNumsInRows.get(row).remove(new Integer(num));
availableNumsInColumns.get(col).remove(new Integer(num));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an item from a `Collection` (which `ArrayList` is part of) when you're iterating with an `Iterator`. You can remove the element from the iterator using `iterator.remove()` instead of `availableNumsInRows.get(row).remove(new Integer(num))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add/remove items to/from a `HashSet` or `HashMap` (which btw is the base class for `HashSet` during iteration. That's causing the exception.

Use the iterator to remove items instead, as Jon Skeet suggested.